# Expand an expression in Maple contening modulus

Tags: complex-numbers, modulus, maple, expansion

I want to develop an expression such as |a+b+c|^2 . I tried the command " expand " but it does not work. ( it works without the modulus )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `expand` is unable to recognize whether `a`, `b` and `c` are positive or negative. So, you make that clear then `expand` will work the way it should.

```
restart:
A:=abs(a+b+c)^2;
assume(a>0,b>0,c>0):expand(A);
```

> a^2+2*a*b+2*a*c+b^2+2*b*c+c^2

if

```
assume(a>0,b>0,c<0):
```

then use

```
expand(simplify(A))
```

Now, lets take three complex numbers and then take its modulus square,

```
B:=abs((a1+b1*I)+(a2+b2*I)+(a3+b3*I))^2;
```

Once again the same issue as above.

```
assume(a1>0,b1<0,a2>0,b2<0,a3<0,b3>0):expand(simplify(B));
```

> a1^2+2*a1*a2+2*a1*a3+a2^2+2*a2*a3+a3^2+b1^2+2*b1*b2+2*b1*b3+b2^2+2*b2*b3+b3^2

Finally, assign some random values for `a's` and `b's` and find modulus,

```
subs(a1=1,a2=1,a3=1,b1=1,b2=2,b3=3,B);
```

Comment: @J.Darmody Feel free to ask here.